# Drawable Images in SQLite android

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite, drawable

I've got a working TextView using database populating text, but I want to connect the image path name in my local database. How can this be incorporated in java?

In the main activity I am setting :

```
String image = currentQ.getImage();
ImageView iView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IS);
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image);
iView.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

In the question:

```
private String image;

/**
* @return the image
*/
public String getImage() {
return image;
}
/**
 * @param image the image to set
 */
public void setImage(String image) {
this.image = image;
}
```

And in the database I am declaring it as a text:

```
file.path.name/drawable/i1.jpg and so on for the others.
```

How can I attach an image file location in my drawable folder for each question in the database and connect it in the java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cant, images in your drawables folder can only be referenced through there id, ie R.drawable.imageName. If you want a static path you will need to do something different, ie put them in asset folder then extract them or as a raw asset.

Comment: How can this be done ? And about my idea of putting the path in the database - i.e. when an answer i selected it moves to the next question and the image is attached to the text presented ??

Comment: How many images are we talking about?

Comment: loads :D 100+ that is my obstacle - thanx

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

String imageName = "NameofImage"; // store only image name in database(means not   store "R.drawable.image") like "image".
            int id = getResources().getIdentifier("projectPackageName:drawable/" + imageName, null, null);
            imageView.setImageResource(id);
```

Comment: Please explain your answers